# Entity Framework the delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables `Employee` (n) and `Store` (1), which have n:1 relationship.

`Employee` has foreign key `idStore` which is primary key from `Store`.

Here is how I try to delete a row from `Employee`:

```
public void deleteEmployee(int idEmployee)
{
   MyEntities pe = new MyEntities();
   try
   {
      var firstQuery = from e in pe.Employees
                       where e.idEmployee == idEmployee
                       select e;
      string findIdStore = firstQuery.First().StoreReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value.ToString();
      int idStore = Int32.Parse(findIdStore);
      Store r = pe.Stores.First(c => c.idStore == idStore);
      r.Employees.Remove(firstQuery.First());
      pe.DeleteObject(firstQuery.First());
      pe.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

And still, I get error that the delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint.

The complete error is here:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Bill_Employee". The conflict occurred in database
>   "myDatabase", table "dbo.Bill", column 'idEmployeeMember'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just find and delete the employee??

```
public void deleteEmployee(int idEmployee)
{
   using(MyEntities pe = new MyEntities())
   {
      var emmployeeToDelete = pe.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.idEmployee == idEmployee);

      if(employeeToDelete != null)
      {
          pe.DeleteObject(employeeToDelete);
          pe.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

I don't think you need to do anything more than this, really.....

Next time when you load this particular store the employee belonged to, that employee will no longer be in the store's collection of employees - without doing any messy manual deletes or anything....

Comment: Nothing. It's a simple table whose primary key is not null. However, if I try to delete the employee with idStore = 1, then if in the Store table there is only one row with idStore=1, it should be deleted. I think that's why this error is happening.

Comment: {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_Bill_Employee\". The conflict occurred
in database \"myDatabase\", table \"dbo.Bill\", column 'idEmployeeMember'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: @Srcee: **READ THE ERROR MESSAGE!!** Obviously there must be a reference between **BILL** and **EMPLOYEE** that you didn't mention anywhere, that is causing the problem! From that messsage, it's clear the problem **isn't** between `Employee` and `Store` - but there is a table `Bill` with a column `idEmployeeMember` which still references the employee you're trying to delete.......